# Windows Browser UI Range Slider (surface pro 3)

Tags: jquery-ui, tablet, uislider, hammer.js, microsoft-edge

does anyone know an ui range slider witch works in edge or chrome on a windows surface pro 3 tablet? When i try for example https://jqueryui.com/slider/ -> the tab works but not the smooth slide!

It's the same in all browser. As far as i figured out hammer.js (http://hammerjs.github.io/) and greenSock (https://greensock.com/draggable) are working.

Version: Windows 10 Pro Version
Browser: tested on lates Chrome Mobile, Windows Edge and Window Explorer 11

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML5 `range` input will render as a slider in all modern browsers, include Microsoft Edge. In addition, because this is a native control, you have full support for pointer, touch, keyboard, and mouse events.

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="500"/>
```

Comment: The problem with the HTML5 range input is it does not allow two handles. A solution would be to use nouislider (https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) or overlap two range sliders with CSS and use javascript to control the min/max values.